# Difference betweeen haarcascade_eye and haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses xml

Tags: node.js, opencv

I have seen there are 2 different Haar Cascade datasets in OpenCV. For an example, take a look at  haarcascade_eye.xml and haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml. what is this tree_eyeglasses thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various Haar Cascades classifiers available. The difference between them is that they have slightly different purposes. Some of the classifiers can detect an eye regardless of whether it is open or closed, some of them can only detect open eyes.

Classifiers which can detect both open and closed eyes include:

- haarcascade_mcs_lefteye.xml
- haarcascade_mcs_righteye.xml
- haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml
- haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml

Classifiers which can only detect open eyes:

- haarcascade_eye.xml
- haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml

And the difference between haarcascade_eye.xml and haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml is that haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml can detect the eyes *if the person is wearing glasses, but is not reliable if they do not wear glasses*. ([Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mastering_OpenCV_with_Practical_Computer.html?id=UjWoIFHcr58C&source=kp_book_description))

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in that there are two or more uses for haarcascades_eye/tree. In the former, you can only capture open eye retinas (the border is designed for arches and circles). In the latter, you can only capture open eyes with glasses or some sort of colored frame. The computer looks first for glasses and moves towards the eye retina.

**If used synonymously, there could be error in your cv2 code.**